# Copy a $_FILE array to a $_SESSION array and make the upload of a file using the $_SESSION array

Tags: php, html, file, session, session-variables

I'm trying to make the upload of a file .pdf in a directory of my server (now I'm using localhost).

The file is chosen using a form with some others parameters (string and mySQL query result) and then passed to another page called controllaData.php using POST method; **in controllaData.php i need to do some operation on others data but not on the file, so to store the file information i copy the $_FILE array to a $_SESSION array**. Now using the function header(Location:) i go to the page uploadFile.php to upload the file but here **i can't do it because the function move_uploaded_file() return False because i haven't passed the file using a POST method.**
Somebody know how to fix it? Some alternative function?

Comment: The temp uploaded file is deleted at the end of the initial upload request (when you do the redirect) if it hasn't been moved.... you need to process it in the request where it's uploaded, even if that's simply moving it to a new temporary location where you can then process it fully with the next request.... but you'll have to clear it up yourself if the next request doesn't validate the file

Comment: So in terms of code what i have to do?
The upload attempt is all in uploadFile.php

sorry for my inexperience but is the first time that i use file with php

Comment: What you have to do is move the uploaded file to a temp file location in the first request, store that temp file location in session, then do your redirect; and all your additional processing in that second request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a form with a file to upload you are not just posting the file name but also the file data which you are not storing anywhere , which is why move_uploaded_file is returning an error. Best way would be to move the file to a location and save the new filepath to a session variable, this way when you need to work on the file, you can use this new path to access it. so:

You are uploading myfile from user form to uploads dir on server( myfile->tempfolder->uploads):

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name") ){
    $_SESSION["uploaded_file"] =  "$uploads_dir/$name";
}
?>
```

Once you are done with your processing :

```
   file_get_contents( $_SESSION['uploaded_file'])
```

Comment: $newfile = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

Is this ok?

Comment: yes it could work but remember it usually is a temp file location which is not reliable for longer duration, you could move file to a safer location and store that as I had done in the answer above

Comment: OK, the complete code is:


$newfile = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $newfile )){
    $_SESSION['filePath']  = $newfile ;
   }

Comment: I just want to know what i have to put in the variable $newfile